# UIActionSheet with disabled buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I wondered if displaying a disabled option in a `UIActionSheet` was a mistake ?

According to Apple guidelines:

> **Use an action sheet to:** Provide alternative ways to complete a task.  An action sheet lets you to provide a range of choices that
>   make sense in the context of the current task, without giving these
>   choices a permanent place in the UI.

So I understand it is better to add buttons in some context and remove it when the context changes. Here I'm looking for some experienced developer answers or feedback about it.

Answer (score 2):

An action sheet provides contextually relevant actions. If an action is unavailable in some context, then it should not be shown. So as you ponder, add and remove actions as appropriate rather than try to disable some actions.